# Matriz que de bordes 1 y de interior 0

Tags: python

El código (Utilizare una matriz de 5X5):

```
M = []
for f in range(5): # f de fila.
    M.append([1])
    for c in range(4): # c de columna.
        M[f].append(0)
```

De momento mi salida es (Que tendria solo tendría el borde de la izquierda):

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Con esto solo tendría el borde de la izquierda...

La pregunta es cómo puedo realizar que (con este código) tenga bordes sean unos y el interior sean ceros.

La idea que quiero hacer es que el bucle for que genera la matriz vaya completando lo que quiero realizar. Por ejemplo: Si estoy en la fila 0 , todas mi columnas (de esa fila) tendrán el valor de 1 y que la fila 1 en la columna 4 sea 1 ... y así sucesivamente.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Quedaría mejor si en vez de agregar el primer elemento de cada fila dentro del primer ciclo, agregaras los cinco en el segundo, comprobando la fila y la columna en la que se encuentra, usando condicionales: https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer de una forma fácil usando una variable que tome el valor de `1` o `0` según corresponda, esto haciendo uso de un operador ternario para facilitar las cosas

```py
M = []
for f in range(5): # f de fila.
    M.append([]) #agregamos una lista vacia
    for c in range(5): # c de columna.
        #si es el inicio o el fin toma el valor de 1
        n = 1 if f in [0,4] or c in [0,4] else 0 
        M[f].append(n)
```

En este caso agregamos una lista vacía y así no tenemos que estar complicándonos porque se nos agregue un elemento de más.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución sencilla:

```
def matriz(filas, columnas):
    return [
         [1] * columnas,
         *([1, *([0] * (columnas - 2)), 1] for i in range(filas - 2)),
         [1] * columnas]
```

La función crea una matriz:

La primera fila son puros '1'.

Desde la segunda hasta la penúltima, cada fila tiene un '1', seguido de `columnas-2` '0', y otro '1' más:

```
[1, *([0] * (columnas - 2)), 1]
```

¿Qué significa el asterisco delante de la expresión en paréntesis? Reemplaza el objeto-lista por sus elementos. Sin asterisco, la expresión produce:

```
[1, [0] * (columnas - 2), 1] =>  [1, [0, 0, 0], 1]
```

Al encerrar la expresión entre `*()` la convierto en

```
[1, *([0] * (columnas - 2)), 1] => [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Esto hay que repetirlo por el número de filas menos 2 (la primera y la última). Se hace con compresión de listas:

```
*([1, *([0] * (columnas - 2)), 1] for i in range(filas - 2))
```

#### Demo

```
def print_matriz(m):
    for fila in m:
        print(fila)
    print()

print_matriz(matriz(3,3))
print_matriz(matriz(4,5))
```

produce:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1]

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende de la flexibilidad que deseas en el código:

1. si deseas siempre una matriz 5x5 con 1 en el borde y 0 en el centro. Puedes directamente plasmarlo así sin necesidad de programarlo:

```py
matrix=[[1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]
print(matrix)
```

2. si no pudieses escribirlo a mano por que el tamaño es muy grande o variable, propongo:

```py
n=6
bordeSup=[1 for m in range(n)] # creas borde superior de tamaño 'n'
bordeInf=bordeSup # creas borde inferior de tamaño 'n'

bordeInt=[1] # creas borde izquierdo con un uno, del borde intermedio (no superior ni inferior)
bordeInt.extend([0 for m in range(n-2)]) # rellenas los 0
bordeInt.append(1) # pones un 1 al final de la fila

matrix=[bordeSup] # pones la primera fila
for m in range(n-2):
    matrix.append(bordeInt) # pones las filas de la mitad
matrix.append(bordeInf) # pones la última fila

print(matrix)
```

También se puede hacer como propones con ciclos for anidados, otra opción es con ayuda de modulos como numpy, el cual tiene la opción de padding. [ver np.pad()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) o módulos de procesamiento de imagenes ya que es usual poner bordes y tienen funciones para ello... por ejemplo openCV.

Comentario final:
Como para cada fila las condiciones no son las mísmas, en concreto para la primera y la última, debes poner una condición esclusiva para ellas. (@Christian) por ejemplo lo hace con condiciones if dentro del bucle for.

Si te fijas todas las filas que obtienes en la salida son iguales, precisamente porque no especificas que diferencie cuando debe estar llena la fila de 1 y cuando solamente el primer y último valor mientras el resto de 0.